# Application form plugin with payment gateway

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm working on a site for a small business academy. We're trying to create an application for potential students to fill out to apply for the school.

The form needs to be able to have multiple long-form questions, (paginated would be nice for each), and before the application is submitted, the students would have to pay an application fee.

Does anyone know of any application form plugins that support these features: paginated questionnaire and payment gateway for application fee?

TIA

Comment: @:Chip : Did you get answer? i wanna do the same.please share what you had done?

Comment: Yes I did. I ended up using Gravity Forms. It's well worth the money for the developer's license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, go with Gravity Forms, it has several options for payment, supports paginated forms and there are even more third party extensions to add payment gateways. Check out [my review](http://yoast.com/wp-plugin-review/gravity-forms/) for some more tips about it.